# bind data to the multiple radio buttons in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have rating star inputs made with the radio buttons. I can add this rating perfectly but when I want to show it on the page or edit it shows me only 1(1 start is highlighted of 5) even if the rating is 5. As I understood angular binds rating to the 1 star only. How can I bind it properly to all the stars??

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Rating</label>
        <fieldset>
          <span class="star-cb-group">
            <input type="radio" id="rating-5" name="rating" [value]=book.rating [(ngModel)] = "book.rating" #r="ngModel"/><label for="rating-5">5</label>
            <input type="radio" id="rating-4" name="rating" [value]=book.rating [(ngModel)] = "book.rating" #r="ngModel"/><label for="rating-4">4</label>
            <input type="radio" id="rating-3" name="rating" [value]=book.rating [(ngModel)] = "book.rating" #r="ngModel"/><label for="rating-3">3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="rating-2" name="rating" [value]=book.rating [(ngModel)] = "book.rating" #r="ngModel"/><label for="rating-2">2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="rating-1" name="rating" [value]=book.rating [(ngModel)] = "book.rating" #r="ngModel"/><label for="rating-1">1</label>
          </span>
          <div class="alert alert-danger"
               *ngIf="r.invalid">
            Rating is required
          </div>
        </fieldset>

      </div>
```

[image]
[image]

the `edit` function below will be called when clicking `submit` button to upload data to database.

```
edit(book) {
    const id = this.activeRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    const updbook = {
      _id: id,
      title: book.title,
      author: book.author,
      description: book.description,
      status: book.status,
      displayStatus: book.displayStatus,
      rating: book.rating
    };
    console.log(book);
    //
    this.bookService.editBook(updbook).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.success) {
        console.log('book edited');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      } else {
        console.log('error book edit');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: To which variable is the model assigned?

Comment: @rick1 this question does not comes under tag of angularjs , it is angular question
angularjs means Angular1 and Angular means Angular2/4

Comment: @Roberto Russo to the book.rating

Comment: title: book.title,
      author: book.author,
      description: book.description,
      status: book.status,
      displayStatus: book.displayStatus,
      rating: book.rating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign same name for multiple radio buttons `name` property, they will become a `radio-button-group`, and only one of them can be setted as checked. Try binding to their `name` property with different names.

---

I would recommend you use `checked` property to set status of radio buttons, and use `click` or `change` event to set `rating`.

```
<input type="radio" [checked]="rating >= 1" (click)="rate(1)">
<input type="radio" [checked]="rating >= 2" (click)="rate(2)">
<input type="radio" [checked]="rating >= 3" (click)="rate(3)">
<input type="radio" [checked]="rating >= 4" (click)="rate(4)">
<input type="radio" [checked]="rating >= 5" (click)="rate(5)">

rate(val) {
  // here setTimeout or ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck will let angular rerender the page according to changes of value
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.book.rating = val;
  });
}
```

**[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PbD3Zv19ilSPe7ThBw3C?p=preview)**

Comment: but how will I save them if they have different names?

Comment: @rick1 can you show how you are setting `book.rating` right now?

Comment: check second pic

Comment: @rick1 see the update part of my answer. Because of a issue of `Zone.js`, I cannot procude this with a plunker right now.

Comment: with the checked it doesnt set status of buttons.

Comment: yes now it is working, but how can I download it to my database? I have method that uploads it to my db, check on the top please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149105/discussion-between-pengyy-and-rick1).